# Pandoc, CSL - em dash to separate author names

Tags: latex, pandoc, csl

I am using pandoc to generate pdf document (through latex). In the references and in citations, I would like to separate author names with em dash. To achieve that, I changed the delimiter to " --- " in the citation style file (.csl) I am using.

I process the markdown file with the -S option with pandoc, however, the three dashes (---) do not get converted to an em dash in the references. It does correctly change them to em dash in the main text. Do you have an idea how to get this work also with references/citations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using an em-dash in the CSL style? (either as the Unicode symbol or escaped HTML character, i.e. "—" or `&#8212;`)